# Should the mutex operation throw a system_error for locking twice?

Tags: c++, mutex, std-system-error

Here is the code

```
mutex mtx;
try{
    mtx.lock();
    mtx.lock();
}catch(system_error& e){
    mtx.unlock();
    cout << e.what() << '\n';
    cout << e.code() << '\n';
}
```

An output `device or resource busy, generic: 16` is expected but never seen.

gcc version 4.8.4

p.s.

Code above is from Bjarne Stroustrup's book -- the C++ programming language, 42.3.1.2 mutex Error. According to the book, a system_error should appear. That question about the "undefined behaviour" is posted in 2012, even before the publication of the book.

Comment: Why do you expect `system_error` to be thrown?

Comment: [Don't see anything in here about throwing exceptions.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)

Comment: "If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the behavior is undefined: the program *may* deadlock, or, if the implementation can detect the deadlock, a resource_deadlock_would_occur error condition may be thrown."

Answer (score 3):

This is undefined behavior. If we look at [mutex.requirements.mutex], it has a prerequisite that the calling thread does *not* own the mutex, and a postcondition that the calling thread *does* own the mutex. `device_or_resource_busy` pertains to when ANOTHER calling thread tries to lock the mutex. However, it's implementation-defined whether or not `resource_deadlock_would_occur` is thrown.

This question is a duplicate of [Why is locking a std::mutex twice 'Undefined Behaviour'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173532/why-is-locking-a-stdmutex-twice-undefined-behaviour?rq=1)