# Why doesn't pthread_mutex_t block, when `g++` compile code

Tags: c++, mutex

This is my test program.I use `g++` to compile code and expect it to block when the function `void foo()` is executed, but it don't block . I don't know what is wrong?  I use `gcc` to compile code, it can block. who can tell me difference.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
static pthread_mutex_t mutex;
void foo()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    cout<<"this is foo()"<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void bar()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    cout<<"this is bar()"<<endl;
    foo();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

  int main()
 {
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    bar();
    return 0;
 }
```

**exepect output**

> this is bar()

**actual output:**

> this is bar()
>
> this is foo()

Comment: Have you checked your mutex type to determine whether it is `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` or `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` (related, since you're outright-ignoring return values) ? (vs. `PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL`, which you appear to be expecting).

Comment: [Undefined Behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173532/why-is-locking-a-stdmutex-twice-undefined-behaviour?rq=1)?

Comment: Actually both mingw and coliru (gcc) shows for me only "this is bar()"

Comment: yes, I have used `gcc` compiled the program. it showed "this is bar()". Howerver, when I use `g++`, it shows for me "this is bar() this is foo()"

Comment: @SergeyA I think we need a pthread mutex dup, not a `std::mutex` one...

Comment: @T.C. I have resolve it. i  forget `-lpthread` when use `g++` to compile code

Comment: @WhozCraig ,I get it, i forget `-lpthread` when use`g++` to compile code

Comment: @marcinj,you are right. I use `g++ -o test -c Mutex.cc` to get executive program. I forget `-lpthread` that is reason of wrong.

Comment: @T.C., you are certainly correct. However, I do not think it matters now.