# Will two overlapping mutexes lead to deadlock?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Consider the following member functions. Will it lead to a deadlock?

```
void foo::insert(item_ptr item)
{
     lock_guard<mutex> lock(mu_);
     items_.insert(item);
} 

void foo::insert(vector<item_ptr> items)
{
      lock_guard<mutex> lock(mu_); // will this lead
                                                        // to deadlock?
      for(auto item:items)
            insert(item);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more information? `foo:insert` is a syntax error. Which of the two are called in 2 separate threads, ...

Comment: Unless they both depend on each other, I wouldn't think so. Can you show us the full class?

Comment: mutex is not re-entrant in conforming C++ library implementations.  So yes.  Use recursive_mutex instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Could use [`recursive_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex) though no? TBH I'm not sure why the vector part needs to lock since the single element overload does.

Comment: Typing from .mobile sucks. I have edited typos.

Comment: If the mutex is nonrecursive, this [seems to be UB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173532/why-is-locking-a-stdmutex-twice-undefined-behaviour).

Comment: The two lock_guards are not overlapping. They would if the second insert called the first one, but this is not the case

Comment: Yeah question edited. Difficulty typing from mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mu_` is a `std::mutex`, then you have a problem.  A std::mutex does not support recursive locks and cannot be locked twice by the same thread.  See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

IF `mu_` is a `std::recursive_mutex`, then you have no problem.  A thread can lock a recursive mutex if it already has it locked.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex